# Upload audio binary file using Alamofire

Tags: swift, post, alamofire, multipartform-data

I'm trying to upload an audio binary file to a server using Alamofire along with parameters and headers. Whenever I add the parameters; I get an error saying **ambigious reference call to member** error. I have checked the API online and haven't found a way to pass in parameters. Is there a way to do so?

```
        let headersFileUpload: HTTPHeaders = ["Authorization": "JWT "+token!]
        let parametersFileUpload: Parameters = ["ctype":"yes"]

        Alamofire.upload(
            multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
                multipartFormData.append(self.getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("recording.m4a"), withName: "iosTest.mp3")
        },
            to: "http://localhost:8000/api/upload",
            method:.post,
            headers:headersFileUpload,
            parameters:parametersFileUpload
            encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                switch encodingResult {
                case .success(let upload, _, _):
                    upload.responseJSON { response in
                        debugPrint(response)
                    }
                case .failure(let encodingError):
                    print(encodingError)
                }
        }
        )
```

Comment: Do u want to upload mutlipart image with alamofire

Comment: I'm want to upload an audio file as binary

Comment: ok. i don't know about audio file

Comment: did you get anywhere with this task? If so, share your solution.